# Loki Broken dependencies. Not sure how to fix (Sudo apt-get install -f won't help)

Tags: release-loki, dependencies, software-sources, sources

So i tried installing DiscordApp and it tells me i got broken dependencies and that i need to run "**Sudo apt-get install -f**"

However doing that yields this error:

```
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic_4.4.0-64.85_amd64.deb
  /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic_4.4.0-62.83_amd64.deb
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Full log for install -f**: http://pastebin.com/yy27igpT

I also tried running **sudo apt autoremove** which also yields a similar problem.

(log for **autoremove**: http://pastebin.com/PXf7H9pT)

Elementary Os is my first linux distro, i'm really liking it so far but since this error occured i have been unable to install programs, updating and similar so it's really blocking me :(

Anyone out there knows how to fix this?

**Solution:** Follow the solution steps on https://askubuntu.com/questions/345588/what-is-the-safest-way-to-clean-up-boot-partition#345611

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says there is no more space on the disk. Try to  remove some packages or delete other files before running `apt-get autoremove` or install.

Comment: But i got 127 gb free on my hard drive? Also how do i delete individual packages?

Comment: Try to look at `df /boot` in a terminal (I think the `/boot` is full where kernel images are stored)

Comment: Thank you for your help! 


This lead me to find this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/345588/what-is-the-safest-way-to-clean-up-boot-partition#345611 

Which helped me solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Use gdebi for everything. In order to install Discord properly you have to use:

`sudo gdebi discord-0.0.1.deb` (or whatever version you have)

It should and will install this application silently.

Comment: Thanks! I will from now on, never even heard of gdebi before